# No sound on Linux or Windows

Tags: linux, windows, audio

I have a laptop and I ran into this problem: the sound doesn't work on either Linux or Windows. It happened when I was on Windows and just put the laptop into sleep mode, and then I opened it and I couldn't see the sound card. After I switched to Linux and there was such a situation that it seemed that I saw a sound card, that's just an Intel sound card, but as I know it should be from Realtek.

This is what the `lspci -v` command outputs:

```
...
00: 1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 131, IOMMU group 10
Memory at df328000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size = 16K]
Memory at df300000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size = 64K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_soc_skl
...
```

By the way, usb also doesn't work(but sometimes it works after several reboots even if the sound doesn't work), although the controller recognizes:

```
...
00: 14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller
Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 125, IOMMU group 3
Memory at df310000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size = 64K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
Kernel modules: xhci_pci
...
```

So after several reboots, the sound may come back, but if I reboot again, the sound will disappear. Maybe the problem is with the sound card? Because when Windows sees the Realtek sound card then the sound works.

Help me please. I don't know what to do

Comment: Is there a BIOS update available for your computer? It seems that [this fixed a similar problem](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?p=1570167#p1570167)

Comment: I also thought about that and recently updated the BIOS to the latest version, but nothing has changed